# changing date range filter type properties

Tags: yadcf

I am using codes as below in my project for range dates

```
var datepickerDefaults = {
    showTodayButton: true,
    showClear: true
};


yadcf.init($Table, [{
      column_number: 0,
      filter_type: "range_date",
      datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker',
      date_format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      filter_plugin_options: datepickerDefaults,
      filter_container_id: "FilterContainer_Date",

  } ],
    {
        cumulative_filtering: true
    }
);
```

I would like to change date range filter **from** and **to** input place holder text and I would like assign default value for **from** and **to** inputs.

Answer (score 2):

OK. I found solution as below;

```
yadcf.init($Table, [{
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: "range_date",
        datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker',
        date_format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        filter_plugin_options: datepickerDefaults,
        filter_container_id: "FilterContainer_Date",
        filter_default_label: ["From Date", "End Date"]

    }],
    {
        cumulative_filtering: true
    }
);

yadcf.exFilterColumn($Table, [
    [0, {
        from: '01/12/2017',
        to: '31/01/2018'
    }],
]);
```